# PHP 5.3 deprecation messages showing up as warnings

Tags: php

I have a legacy app that requires `register_globals` and `magic_quotes_gpc` to be enabled. I have my `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED` because I still want to see any warnings.

When I run the PHP CLI I get the following

```
$ php -d "error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED" -v
PHP Warning:  Directive 'register_globals' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Mar 30 2011 13:51:41)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by Derick Rethans
```

Why is it showing the deprecation messages as warnings? Shouldn't they be in the `E_DEPRECATED` level?

It seems I have to not show warnings to get them to go away

```
$ php -d "error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_WARNING" -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Mar 30 2011 13:51:41)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by Derick Rethans
```

I could change my `error_reporting` to `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_WARNING` but then it wouldn't show warnings for my webapp. Any suggestions? Do I have to use a separate `php.ini` for the CLI?

Comment: It's programmed in as E_WARNING. And that is that. (Btw, both warnings would be easy to fix.)

Comment: You should turn off both directives. They are bad bad ideas.

Comment: @Ondřej Mirtes just quoting the OP, because it seems you missed the first line: "I have a legacy app that requires register_globals and magic_quotes_gpc to be enabled."

Answer (score 2):

Change `error_reporting` to `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_WARNING`.

Then, at the beginning of your code set:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Initial PHP checks have passed and now you have your complete error-reported environment. :)

Answer (score 1):

[LMGTFY](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49362)

**The best REPLY**

> [2009-09-07 08:42 UTC] jani@php.net
>   Yes. It's not E_DEPRECATED, it's E_WARNING and that's not gonna change.
>
> [2010-03-23 14:26 UTC] kalle@php.net
>   aks at esoft dot dk > If the documentation indeed says that, then report it as a separate issue instead of bumping an already closed report.

Looks like you have to accept the way of how it is behave.
The changes will only apply to v6

Answer (score 0):

It's considered best practice to not use either. They're `E_WARNING`s because those are the type of errors that the developers have chosen to trigger (it's arbitrary to use one versus another at that level).

I highly recommend that you make sure those features are turned off in your configuration, or that if you can't avoid it, just turn those types of warnings off in the configuration. Otherwise, you risk it ruining an AJAX request. We all have to cope with it.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck turning off the [display of startup errors](http://php.net/errorfunc.configuration#ini.display-startup-errors).  The errors should still get logged to your error log, but they won't be displayed in your application's output.

Comment: I have `display_startup_errors = Off` and still get the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

you could try registering your error handler with

```
set_error_handler("myFunc");
```

and myFunc is something like:

```
myFunc($errno,$errstr) {
    return strpos($errstr,"register_globals")===false ? false : true;
}
```

so, if string "register_globals" is not found, func returns false and standard error handling starts, otherwise it just returns true and nothing happens.